# Trigger a second SVG SMIL animation on hover of the first

Tags: animation, svg, smil

I'm attempted to trigger a second SMIL animation when you hover over another.

The first animation runs fines and so does the second when it's got it's own hover/click trigger on it however when i try connect the two with

```
begin="pin-anime.begin + 1s"
```

on the first animation runs.

Any ideas what i'm missing here?

[JSFiddle of what i have so far](https://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/e15z5qsd/)

Answer (score 1):

You've a couple of separate bugs.

- Your animation element has no id value. It looks like you've mistyped d instead of id but in any case all id values must be unique.
- Your animation element has an id with a minus sign in. This is interpreted as an invalid time offset. You can either use ids without minus signs or escape the minus sign with \ as in `begin="pin\-anim.begin + 1s"`

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/e15z5qsd/2/) seems to be closer to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. The changes you've made have had no effect on starting the second paths animation.

Comment: What UA are you using because the fiddle works for me on Firefox. If I put the mouse over the top shape, the bottom shape starts pulsing after 1 second. Isn't that what you wanted to happen?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I had opened it in Chrome. That's strange that it's not working in Chrome. I thought the only browser that didn't support SMIL are IE and Opera.

Comment: could be a bug in Chrome's implementation. These days Chome and Opera have the same platform so they will have the same SMIL support.

Comment: Nightmare. Thanks for your help Robert.